Issue with group by on left join attempting to calculate totals
I have the following table (dummy data):



project
keyword_id
listing_id
clicks
ctr
impressions
pos
date




1
1
2
3
4
5
6
2024-04-14


1
1
3
3
4
5
6
2024-04-14


1
2
4
5
6
7
8
2024-04-14


1
2
5
5
6
7
8
2024-04-14



I have the following code:
SELECT  AAA.date,
        IFNULL(SUM(BBB.impressions),0) impressions,
        IFNULL(SUM(BBB.clicks),0) clicks,
        IFNULL(SUM(BBB.ctr),0) ctr,
        IFNULL(AVG(BBB.pos),0) pos
            FROM
            (
                SELECT date
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) +
                        INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW())-1) MONTH +
                        INTERVAL daynum DAY date
                    FROM
                    (
                        SELECT t*10+u daynum
                        FROM
                            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
                            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
                            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
                            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
                        ORDER BY daynum
                    )  AA
                )  AA WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(NOW())
            ) AAA LEFT JOIN (SELECT date,impressions,clicks,ctr,pos FROM table WHERE project=:project) BBB
            USING (date) GROUP BY date ORDER BY date;

Impressions, clicks, ctr are pulled from Google Search Console API based on the keyword which means that the data for each listing will have the same data for each keyword. What is happening is that it is obviously summing all of the values. What I am trying to do is get the grouped sum of each row but only taking into account one row per keyword. If I add GROUP BY keyword_id to the left join, it returns the following which is not correct:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2024-04-01
            [1] => 2024-04-02
            [2] => 2024-04-03
            [3] => 2024-04-04
            [4] => 2024-04-05
            [5] => 2024-04-06
            [6] => 2024-04-07
            [7] => 2024-04-08
            [8] => 2024-04-09
            [9] => 2024-04-10
            [10] => 2024-04-11
            [11] => 2024-04-12
            [12] => 2024-04-13
            [13] => 2024-04-14
            [14] => 2024-04-15
            [15] => 2024-04-16
            [16] => 2024-04-17
            [17] => 2024-04-18
            [18] => 2024-04-19
            [19] => 2024-04-20
            [20] => 2024-04-21
            [21] => 2024-04-22
            [22] => 2024-04-23
            [23] => 2024-04-24
            [24] => 2024-04-25
            [25] => 2024-04-26
            [26] => 2024-04-27
            [27] => 2024-04-28
            [28] => 2024-04-29
            [29] => 2024-04-30
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 292
            [5] => 65
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [15] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [18] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [20] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 0
            [24] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [29] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [15] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [18] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [20] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 0
            [24] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [29] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [11] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [13] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [15] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [18] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [20] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [23] => 0
            [24] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [29] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.0000
            [1] => 0.0000
            [2] => 0.0000
            [3] => 0.0000
            [4] => 10.0000
            [5] => 9.0000
            [6] => 0.0000
            [7] => 0.0000
            [8] => 0.0000
            [9] => 0.0000
            [10] => 0.0000
            [11] => 0.0000
            [12] => 6.1667
            [13] => 0.0000
            [14] => 0.0000
            [15] => 0.0000
            [16] => 0.0000
            [17] => 0.0000
            [18] => 0.0000
            [19] => 0.0000
            [20] => 0.0000
            [21] => 0.0000
            [22] => 0.0000
            [23] => 0.0000
            [24] => 0.0000
            [25] => 0.0000
            [26] => 0.0000
            [27] => 0.0000
            [28] => 0.0000
            [29] => 0.0000
        )

)

If I add the group by to the existing group by at the end of the statement it will not group the dates anymore but the values will be correct (I did add the array of results but it made the post too long).
I have searched and searched for the solution to this and have not been able to work out how to get total clicks, ctr, impressions, and average position for the current month by day. If anyone would be able to advise on how I can achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

that looks like a pohp putput can you provide a "normal" result table and mysql 8 has redursve cte which can provide the wanted dates
